# @font-face .ttf is causing slow load times

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a site and am linking a typeface in the `CSS` using @font-face and it seems to be affecting the pageload speed.

I've tried preloading the typeface in the header but can't seem to get the font to load quicker than 4/5 seconds. How can I circumvent this long load time?

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Helvetica Neue Black;
    src: url("../fonts/Helvetica-Neue-LT-Std-93-Black-Extended_22550.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" href="assets/fonts/Helvetica-Neue-LT-Std-93-Black-Extended_22550.ttf" type="font/truetype" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

[image: onLoad]

[image: afterLoad]

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess file? Try using expire headers for .ttf files

Comment: Thanks for the advice; would this help even if the site is being run locally?

Comment: hi again, I'm actually not 100% sure but you could try uploading your site to your domain and then use https://tools.pingdom.com/ to check your page loading time.